# app crashing while executing doInBackground() with google maps api nearby places search

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers

im create an apps with bottom navigation bar with 3 activity : home,maps and turney. i have a problem with maps activity with error about async task and null pointer, when i trying to run an app, then app was crasing when press button to find  nearby place then redirect into home tabs with this error.

this is an error that i get

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: com.truesight, PID: 7503
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
    at com.truesight.Maps$ParserTask.doInBackground(Maps.java:276)
    at com.truesight.Maps$ParserTask.doInBackground(Maps.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

this is an async in my Maps Activity

```
private class PlaceTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String data = null;
        try {
            //initialize data
            data = downloadUrl(strings[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        //execute parser task
        new ParserTask().execute(s);
    }
}

private String downloadUrl(String string) throws IOException {
    //initialize URL
    URL url = new URL(string);
    //initialize connection
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    //Connect connection
    connection.connect();
    //initialize input stream
    InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
    //initialize buffer reader
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    //Initialize string builder
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    //initialize string variable
    String line = "";
    //use while loop
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        //append line
        builder.append(line);
    }
    //get append data
    String data = builder.toString();
    //close reader
    reader.close();
    //return data
    return data;


}

private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>> {
    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        //create json parser class
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        //initialize Hash Map list
        List<HashMap<String,String>> mapList = null;
        JSONObject object;
        try {
            //initialize json object
            object = new JSONObject(strings[0]);
            //parse json object
            mapList = jsonParser.parseResult(object);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mapList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> hashMaps) {
        //clear map
        map.clear();
        //use for loop
        for (int i=0; i<hashMaps.size(); i++){
            //initialize hash map
            HashMap<String,String> hashMapList = hashMaps.get(i);
            //get latitude
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(hashMapList.get("lat"));
            //get longitude
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(Objects.requireNonNull(hashMapList.get("lng")));
            //get name
            String name = hashMapList.get("name");
            //concat latitude and longitude
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat,lng);
            //initialize marker option
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
            //set position
            options.position(latLng);
            //set title
            options.title(name);
            //add marker on map
            map.addMarker(options);
        }
    }
,}
```

Comment: if(s!=null) new ParserTask().execute(s);

Comment: @blackapps on which line should I add it ?

Comment: You should replace the old line by this.